# Get a stream resource from a SplFileInfo object

Tags: php, spl, splfileobject

I'm calling a method that expects a stream resource for a file, like this:

```
$obj->method(fopen($splFileInfo, 'r+'));
```

The `$splFileInfo` object is an instance of `SplFileInfo`.

Is there a way to get the stream resource of the `$splFileInfo` object without having to call `fopen`?

Comment: It appears not :( https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44392

Comment: The ability to retrieve a stream resource from `SplFileInfo` doesn't make too much sense (since they don't have to be used with files that actually exist), but it would be nice to introduce the ability for the `SplFileObject` class (as in the bug report Anthony mentioned) which should have a stream resource available internally.